# State: are they permanent?

Tags: 8

I'm using StateAPI to store some variables that shouldn't be exported as configurations.

These values are stored in the database, in the *key_value* table.

Is this a "secure" table? Are there tasks (cache-clear or other) that could automatically remove values from this table?

Is it a good idea to create a custom form to let users to set some states?
They could be simple strings, or url, and I think that create nodes for this information is too "heavy".

Answer (score 4):

> Is this a "secure" table?

Depends on what you mean by secure.

> Are there tasks (cache-clear or other) that
>   could automatically remove values from this table?

No.

> Is it a good idea to create a custom form to let users to set some
>   states?

This is kind of looking at it from the wrong direction. States are a solution to an issue. If you have something that is to be stored, for which states are a good solution, then they are good to use. In other words, if you have a form that does something that states would be good for, then use states. Deciding to use states then creating forms for them doesn't really make sense.

Answer (score 1):

The state service is never used to store data that is edited by users; it is used to store data necessary for a module the module doesn't expose to users through a form for its settings.
The classic example of using the state service is storing the last time cron tasks have been executed, or the last time a feed has been checked. Those values aren't exposed to users (even the users with a specific permission), and users don't have the possibility to reset those values. They are values required from a site to work, but they aren't imported and exported to a different site.

As for the difference between content and configuration, I would follow this simple rule: If you are storing information about your site that doesn't change so frequently, then it is probably [configuration](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/configuration-api); if then it's information a *site editor* role would want to edit, then it's content.

To answer your question, no: The information stored with the *state* service is not automatically deleted after X minutes are passed.

Comment: I agree with you, but there are some exception. I'm working on a site that has, in the footer, a big link to a google form. Only the url of this link should ben editable by the user. Should I use a node only to store this url?

Comment: I would use a configuration entity which is editable by user with an _administer ..._ permission.

Comment: Ok, but if the editor change the conf and I've a deploy? With drush cim this conf is overriden. Perhaphs I should to exclude that conf from export..

Comment: It depends. If you want the setting to be the same across Drupal instances, you would use configuration. If you want it to be different, you would use State.

Comment: @arrubiu The previous comment was the reply to your question.

Comment: @kiamlaluno - regarding your comment that "The state service is never used to store data that is edited by users", I'm using it to store an admin setting, that will differ by environment, and therefore do not want it to be able to be synced through the config API. I'm wondering if the 'users' in your comment is meant to refer to any user, or just non-admins.

Comment: @Jaypan I am referring to the Drupal core's usage of the state API. Maybe the sentence comes out too strong, as I wrote it. The documentation says _Data which needs to be edited by humans or needs to be shared between environments should use `\Drupal::config()` instead._ I will edit my answer to make it clearer.

Comment: @kiamlaluno thanks. So in your esteemed opinion, is my use-case in my comment better off served through a separate API since it's user-edited data? Or is this a valid usage of the state API?

Comment: @Jaypan Basing on the documentation, I would say yes, this is the case for using a custom service. Then, it depends also from what the module does with the value entered from users. If it is just saved, then a custom service it's what the documentation seems to suggest; if the input from the users is used for calculating something, or as parameter for calculating something that is then saved, the state API could be what you are looking for.